# I can't find the docker command

Tags: linux, docker

#### Assumptions and what you want to achieve

I can't find "dokcer" command after installing with "sudo apt install docker" on Linux.
How do I use docker on Linux?
Also, if this is a PATH problem, I'd like to know which folder it was in.

#### Occurring problems and error messages

```
bash: docker: command not found
```

#### The corresponding source code

```
$ docker
```

#### Supplementary information (e.g. FW/tool version)

- MX Linux

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Then you would have `docker` cli command